# What is an easier way for 'checkbox' to 'show div'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Currently i am using css, which seemed fine, until i realized i needed alot of these 'checkbox to show div', im assuming there is some beautiful jquery method to do this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/0qnsvgcw/

```
<style>
    #part1, #part2 {display: none;} 

    #reveal-part1:checked ~ #part1{display: inline-block;}
    #reveal-part1:checked ~ .qntylabel{margin-right: 0px;}

    #reveal-part2:checked ~ #part2{display: inline-block;}
    #reveal-part2:checked ~ .qntylabel{margin-right: 0px;}
</style>

<html>
<input type="checkbox" id="reveal-part1" class="apple-switch"><span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPON</span>
<div id="part1"><input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY"/></div>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="reveal-part2" class="apple-switch"><span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPOS</span>
<div id="part2"><input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY"/></div>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "easier"? What is it, exactly, you expect would be different with 'some jquery method' instead of how you're currently doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would still be with CSS. You can make the logic more generic by wrapping each set of elements in a container, such as a `div` in the following example, then placing common classes on each element which you can then use in the CSS. Try this:

```css
.part {
  display: none;
}

.reveal:checked ~ .part {
  display: inline-block;
}

.reveal:checked ~ .qntylabel {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal">
  <span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPON</span>
  <div class="part">
    <input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal">
  <span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPOS</span>
  <div class="part">
    <input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal">
  <span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPOS</span>
  <div class="part">
    <input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal">
  <span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPOS</span>
  <div class="part">
    <input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace IDs (`#`) to a class (`.`) in your CSS, then write the HTML in a structurally identical manner. This way, you can apply the styles to multiple cases of the HTML.

```css
.toggle ~ .toggle-target {
  display: none
}

.toggle:checked ~ .toggle-target {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle"><span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPON</span>
  <div class="toggle-target"><input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" /></div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle"><span class="qntylabel">10 PIN COMPOS</span>
  <div class="toggle-target"><input type="text" id="" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" /></div>
</div>
```